# How to solve $c^2={b^2}{\sin(C)^2}+(b\cdot \cos(C) - a)^2$ for C?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

What is $c^2={b^2}{\sin(C)^2}+(b\cdot \cos(C) - a)^2$ when solving for C?
I am trying to figure out a formula for finding the length of the third side of a triangle with two sides and an angle given, but I'm stuck at the last step.
I tried isolating both $\sin(C)$ and $\cos(C)$
( $\cos(C) = \frac{a}{b} - \sqrt{\frac{c^2}{b^2}-\sin(C)^2}$ and $\sin(C) = \sqrt{-(\cos(C) - \frac{a + c}{b})(\cos(C) - \frac{a - c}{b})}$ respectively), but I have no idea how to get C by itself. I have been trying for hours and I have no idea what to do.

Comment: I've been using Desmos to try and make the formula, here's the link to my graph incase you need it: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1srliecsot

Comment: since $\sin(C)^2+\cos(C)^2=1$, you obtain a linear equation in $\cos(C)$ that is easy to solve.

Comment: This is just the Law of Cosines.

Comment: $$c^2 = b^2[\sin^2(C) + \cos^2(C)] + a^2 - 2ab ~\cos(C) \implies $$ $$c^2 = b^2 + a^2 - 2ab ~\cos(C).$$

Comment: Thanks! I know this was solved, I just wanted an explanation of why, and thanks for that! makes it work better in my head if I can "see" it, how I would model it step by step on a graph.